# Problema con Pyttsx3: se convierte el texto a voz, pero no se muestra el número en la etiqueta

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación el cual pasa un código de barras, busca el EAN en una base de datos, y me devuelve una posición. Ese número (que es la posición), lo convierto a "voz" (con Pyttsx3), y para ayuda del usuario, a ese mismo número lo muestro en una etiqueta.
El problema que estoy teniendo, es que sí convierte el texto a voz, pero no me pinta el número en la etiqueta que tengo como objetivo.

Aquí esta mi código. Creo que el problema radica en el `engine.runAndWait()`.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget
from views.ventanaPrincipal import UiPrincipal
from logica.logicageneral import *
import time


numero = 0
capacidad = 0
biner = 0
tarima = ''
cajas = 0

class VistaPrincipal(QWidget, UiPrincipal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.lineEdit_Dum.returnPressed.connect(self.verificar_sku)




    def verificar_sku(self):

        escan = self.lineEdit_Dum.text()

        if len(escan) != 13:
            self.label_NumTarima.setText('Error')
            self.lineEdit_Dum.clear()
            return
        else:
            existe = get_existe_sku(escan)
            if existe == 0:
                self.label_NumTarima.setText('No Existe')
                return
            else:
                self.obtener_globales_sku(escan)
                self.reproducir_a_voz('T' + str(numero))

                self.label_NumTarima.setText('')
                self.label_CapacidadTarima.setText('')
                self.lineEdit_Dum.setText('')

    def obtener_globales_sku(self, texto):
        global numero, capacidad, biner, cajas
        numero, capacidad, biner, cajas = obtener_info_sku(texto)
        self.label_NumTarima.setText(str(numero))
        self.label_CapacidadTarima.setText(str(cajas))

    def reproducir_a_voz(self, texto):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        vol = 1
        voice_id = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_ES-ES_HELENA_11.0'
        engine.setProperty('voice', voice_id)
        engine.setProperty('volume', vol)
        rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
        engine.setProperty('rate', rate + 10)
        engine.say(texto)
        engine.runAndWait()
```